# Get all open WPF windows

Tags: c#, wpf, windows

I'm trying to get all open windows. I tried to use `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows` but I get Null Pointer Exception in line where `foreach` loop is. Do anyone has idea what is wrong?

```
public Window getWindow(String Title)
{
    Window windowObject = null;
    Console.WriteLine("Inside getWindow");
    foreach (Window window in System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows)
    {
        if (window.Title == Title)
        {
            windowObject = window;
        }
    }
    return windowObject;
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? What is `null`? `System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows`? `System.Windows.Application.Current`?

Comment: either `Application`, `Current` or `Windows` is null. If you put a breakpoint on the line before, you'll be able to find out in the debugger.

Comment: Is your application a WPF application?

Comment: Yes, it is WPF application. I'm using White framework to automate Windows GUI but I need to get window which belong to "Desktop" so I need to switch from application which I run to the Desktop window. P.S. I debugged it and Current is null.

Comment: Where are you calling that method? Is the entry point of your WPF application non-standard? If you start it in debug mode going step by step (`F11`), where does it get you? Isn't `getWindow` (should be `GetWindow` by .NET convention, but that's another story) called before the `App` object is instantiated?

Comment: According to this MSDN forum question: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/27cf81ef-ede4-4a70-beda-53fed697df7d then this method will work as long as you create an application object in your application startup code.

Comment: The application is launched by Application.Launch method which comes with White Framework. I haven't found any way to get other opened windows after application launch using White Framework - it only finds launched window. That's the reason why I tried to use System Property. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can  use Process.GetProcesses to get Window handle of another process and then use P/Invoke to send messages to it.

Comment: @Anurag Ranjhan - but how after that cast process type to Window?

Comment: You can't, it belongs to another [AppDomain](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116429/get-window-instance-from-window-handle)

Comment: So this solution won't help me.

Answer (score 12):

This is how you cycle through all opened windows in an running application in WPF:

```
foreach (Window w in Application.Current.Windows)
{ 
    // TODO: write what you want here
}
```

If you want know in windowforms use application instead of app.
bye.

Comment: I don't see a substantial difference beyond syntax sugar compared to the code already present in the question. Actually, your code only works if you have an `App` class in your project derived from `System.Windows.Application`. Even if this is the case, you should rather refer to the static property using `Application.Current`.

Comment: The Question is related About WPF , an my answer is for WPF, that's all.

Answer (score 4):

Either `Current` or `Windows` is `null`

The [Windows property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.windows.aspx) can only be access from the thread that created the Application object and this will only work in a WPF application AFTER the application object has been created.

Comment: How does Window class apply to WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Bare in mind that System.Windows is a namespace, and Application is the actual class that *references* the current application context. What this means is that ´Application.Current.Windows´ only references all windows spawned by the application itself. Try to loop through all windows and print their title.

What happens in your program, is that the if statement will always be false, unless Title is equal to a window spawned by the Application, thus windowObject will remain to be null, and null will be returned by the method.