# how to get count of number of opened windows in WPF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf, windows

I have a requirement that, if one `window` is opened then user can not allow to open other `window`, for that I have tried following code.

```
if(System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.Count == 0)
 {    
 //My code
 }
```

I am checking for currently opened `window` count, if it is greater then 1 then user can not open other window and that I will mention inside if statement,

but when I run this code it gives me the error

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Any Solution

Comment: Are you trying to check a particular window is already opened or if any window is opened from your application?

Answer (score 1):

You would be probably getting this error because, even for the first windows to be loaded, you would be applying this check. For this you can apply null check in your code.
and for list of loaded windows, you can get it using Application,

```
var loadedWindows = Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>()
                                               .Where(win => win.IsLoaded);
```

Comment: thanks for the help rohit, but when I am using your solution then also I am getting the same error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

 var loadedWindows = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().Where(win => win.IsLoaded);

Comment: @SagarPatel, Probably you would be getting Nullreference because of some other null variable. Could you please write some more code where you have written this code.

Comment: `var loadedWindows = System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().Where(win => win.IsLoaded);`

**During debugging, when compiler come to above line, at that time it is giving error**. i have also checked

`if(System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows != null)`. Any mistake with System.Windows.Application.Current.Windows  ?

Comment: @SagarPatel, ok. Could you please write the stack trace you can see in the exception more details.

Comment: `at MS.CMG.EBT.UI.EXCELWORKBOOK.EBTRibbon.btnManageTaxonomy_Click(Object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) in d:\EBTTool\Main\UI\MS.CMG.EBT.UI.EXCELWORKBOOK\EBTRibbon.cs:line 1012`

Comment: I'm getting same error when i use `foreach( Window window in Application.Current.Windows )`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12177224/2111892 You're question is tagged with ASP.NET and WPF, you sure, you have any windows?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know how many windows are opened from your application instance, you can do this

```
 l_WindowCount = 0;

 foreach(var Window in App.Current.Windows)
 {
    l_WindowCount += 1
 }

if(l_WindowCount > 1)
{
//do what you want to do here
}
```

Comment: which is the same as: Application.Current.Windows.Count