# Check If window Is Open on WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, window

My program has a  MainWindow and a SecondWindow, which is called by the first one like this:

```
SecondWindow config = new SecondWindow();
config.Owner = this;
config.Show();
```

Those lines are contained on a `Button.Click` method. And I want to check if it is already open, close it or do not open it. 
Thanks!

Comment: You need to store the instance so you can check its properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get all open WPF windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12177133/get-all-open-wpf-windows)

Answer (score 0):

Do not create a new instance. Just add it to **top of your MainWindow class**, and when you click the button, use `secondWindow.Hide();`. **You must hide**, because if you close it, **you can't show it again**. If you want to **do not open it**, **activate** the window and take it to **top of desktop with** `secondWindow.Activate();`.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if(Application.Current.Windows.OfType<SecondWindow>().FirstOrDefault() ==  null)
{
  //second window not exist
}
```